# heroku not loading images from vendor .css file

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku, sass, asset-pipeline

https://github.com/christoph88/kratos/tree/create-landingpage

**I cannot load images from my CSS file in production on heroku. On my development server it works perfectly.**

I tried doing this:

```
#config/environments/production.rb
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.digest = true

#cmd
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
git add. 
git commit -a -m "Your Commit"
git push heroku master
heroku run rake assets:precompile --app your_heroku_app
```

With no effect.

The images are stored under the assets/images folder. The css file that loads the images is located under /vendor/stylesheets/landingpage/style.css

It is a .css file so I am not using the ruby or sass helpers for images but just e.g. url(bgTop.jpg)

I tried renaming the file to .css.scss and using the image-url("bgTop.jpg") helper but that also has no effect.

Comment: Possibly, I can help, but I need more information from you. Using a browser debugging tool what do you see as the full url for the image in question?

Comment: Thanks, on dev and production I see url(bgTop.jpg) in chrome. when I click it open I get following URL's: url(https://kratos-christoph88.c9.io/assets/landingpage/bgTop.jpg); for development and https://kratosapp.herokuapp.com/assets/bgTop.jpg on production (heroku)

Comment: On development the images are displayed properly, on heroku they aren't. The css file is in a subfolder (landingpage) and I can not get the helpers to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working bij renaming my css file to .css.scss and **using the image_url( helper**. Next within the helper I needed to put the subdirectory so image_url("landingpage/bgTop.jpg")

I also needed to add **all images subdirectories to  the asset pipeline**.

**application.rb**

```
# add all asset pipeline images sub folders
    Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/**/").each do |path|
      config.assets.paths << path
    end
```

And enabling some stuff in **production.rb**

```
  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = true

  # Generate digests for assets URLs.
  config.assets.digest = true
```

Answer (score -1):

Just put the full path in css including the heroku path.

e.g.: https://floating-wave-85895.herokuapp.com/images/